# In springboot application how to set default header if not present

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have written a method with get request mapping it gives list of users. As jakson binding dependency is there is gives response in JSON. I've also dependency for XML which is Jackson Dataformat XML.So, if Accept is application/json it returns the response in JSON and if it is in application/xml it returns in XML.But by default it gives JSON response. SO, I wanted to add **Accept** header if not present and make it's default value as application/xml.

```
@GetMapping(path="/getAll")
    public List<User> getUsers(@RequestHeader(value= "Accept" ,required=false, defaultValue="application/xml") String Accept)
    {
        return service.findAll();
    }
```

But in above case, the header is not setting.

Comment: I haven't tried this method yet, but here is my idea. Maybe we can use a filter to add the default header value as: http://wilddiary.com/adding-custom-headers-java-httpservletrequest/

Answer (score 2):

In order to do so, you need to modify your controller method to return `ResponseEntity<List<User>>` as following:

```
@GetMapping(path="/getAll")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers(@RequestHeader(value= "Accept" ,required=false, defaultValue="application/xml") String Accept) {

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setLocation(location);
    responseHeaders.set("Accept", "Value");
    return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(service.findAll(), responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Comment: It is also returning json response.

Comment: That is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to respond XML from your spring boot application, use the following custom `webMvcConfiguration`. Setting a default `Accept` header just to respond XML does not seem like a good idea.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer myWebMvcConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

if you are already using a custom `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`, just override the `configureContentNegotiation(...)` method as above.